# :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, ionic

Desde que actualicé la versión del CLI de ionic, ya que lo estaba pidiendo el mismo, he tenido unos problemas, pero solamente con proyectos nuevos, no se si se deba a algún conflicto, el problema surge al tratar de compilar y obtener mi apk.

> :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

La información de mi sistema es la siguiente:

```
C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
OS: Windows 10 32Bits
Node Version: v5.5.0

C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp>java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101
```

Este proceso ocurre durante la compilación, cuando ejecuto el comando `ionic build android`

```
C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\pedromiguel\aplicacionesIonic\testsignalApp


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\pedromiguel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac


:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pedromiguel\.gradle\caches\2.13\classAnalysis\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 40.031 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pedromiguel\.gradle\caches\2.13\classAnalysis\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: La pude resolver, dos archivos diferentes en el carpeta *.gradle*, que tenian una extensión que no era la indicada, y renombre los archivos quitando esa extensión a ambos, y ahora funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error lo pude solucionar eliminando una *extensión extra* que tenia el archivo en este caso el correcto es

`cache.properties`

Y estaba de la siguiente forma

`cache.properties.otraextension`

Y por eso no reconocía o no encontraba el archivo.